# Query Optimization/Performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a sql query which is performing badly, It is causing table scans / IO spikes. Please check the below script and the execution plan and let me know if it requires any indexes or refactoring of the query itself. Thanks

--Query

```
SELECT TOP 20
        CustomerPrimaryExtID,
        Max(POSTimeStamp) AS TransactionDate,
        ExtLocationCode,
        0 AS RedemptionAmount,
        0 AS RedemptionCount,
        TerminalNum,
        LogixTransNum,
        POSTransNum AS TransNum,
        0 AS DetailRecords,
        CustomerTypeID,
        PresentedCustomerID,
        PresentedCardTypeID,
        HHID,
        Replayed,
        0 AS TransContext,
        ISNULL(TransTotal, 0) AS TransTotal
    FROM TransHist AS TH WITH(nolock)
    WHERE 
        ( 
            ( 
                ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' ) AND HHID IS NULL )
                OR HHID = '0000000250000007320' AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 
            )   OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000007320'   AND CustomerTypeID = 1 )
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                    LogixTransNum
                FROM   TransRedemptionView AS TR2
                WHERE  
                    (
                        ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )  AND HHID IS NULL )  OR HHID = '0000000250000007320' AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )
                        OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000007320'   AND CustomerTypeID = 1 )
                    )
                    AND TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum
        )
    GROUP  BY
        CustomerPrimaryExtID,
        HHID,
        CustomerTypeID,
        PresentedCustomerID,
        PresentedCardTypeID,
        LogixTransNum,
        POSTransNum,
        TerminalNum,
        ExtLocationCode,
        Replayed,
        TransTotal
    ORDER  BY TransactionDate DESC
```

Comment: where is the execution plan you mentioned in your post? :)

Comment: I tried to upload it as a pic, but it is not working. Is there any other way to upload it here?

Comment: ah well you might not have enough reputation to do that yet, you would have to upload it to another site and link here or include your execution plan in text form

Comment: Here is the link for the execution plan: http://www.flickr.com/photos/101538921@N05/

Comment: thats not the whole thing right? ok i see costs 97% and 3% there so that is probably the most significant part, but you can also get a text-based execution plan if you enable `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` in management studio then you will get additional result with the plan

Comment: one thing I see is you can replace `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT LogixTransNum....` with `AND (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ...) IS NOT NULL` that way the query wont have to retrieve the actual value, but thats just a small tweak will probably not give you much speed

Comment: `CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )` is this really nessecary? why not directly compare it with `=`?

Comment: is there an index on `CustomerPrimaryExtID` is it really a `VARCHAR` column? since there is a table scan in the execution, I suppose there is no index on that column. So you should try create one and get rid of the `CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )` logic then table scan should become an index seek

Comment: The problem is on the NOT EXISTS into the where clause, which calls TransRedemptionView which is - i suppose - a view. The optimizer cannot join the table with the view (most likely) so it calls the view multiple times, if not at every row, on order to filter properly and apply the NOT EXISTS.

To verify that, simply run the statement WITHOUT the NOT EXISTS (i know it is not equivalent) to measyre the performance. How fast it is? 2 times? 100 times? This will give you a first clue.

You will also need to post the view code (TransRedemptionView) for proper optimization.